# How to estimate numerical bin for Integro-differential equation system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, error-propagation, numerical-calculus, integro-differential-equations

I try to solve an integro-differential equation system numerically (with [LSODA](https://computing.llnl.gov/casc/odepack/odepack_home.html).) The system is following: ( $'$ is the derivation w.r.t. $x$)

$y'(x,s_{1}) = f(x,y(x,s_{1}),I[y(x,s)])\\
y'(x,s_{2}) = f(x,y(x,s_{2}),I[y(x,s)])\\
\vdots \\
y'(x,s_{n}) = f(x,y(x,s_{n}),I[y(x,s)])\\$

LHS, inside of $f$, includes also integration of $y(x,s)$ over $s$ , $I[y(x,s)]$ (Thank you @Lutz for notation correction ). For the optimized numerical calculation, I discrete $y(x,s)$ $n$ times for both integral and number of system i.e. system has $n$ differential equation and integral at LHS is discreted $n$ times.

Do you suggest any generic condition for $n$ determination? If I take big $n$ for better integration, the system gets huge and numerical solving is getting slow. Small $n$ makes error of integral bigger which I do not want.

**Edit 1:**

Example: Equations

$y'(x,s_{1}) = e^{x}\int_{0}^{\pi}y(x,s)ds\\
y'(x,s_{2}) = e^{x}\int_{0}^{\pi}y(x,s)ds\\
\vdots \\
y'(x,s_{n}) = e^{x}\int_{0}^{\pi}y(x,s)ds\\$

Here, LHS function is $f(x,y(x,s_{n}))=e^{x}\int_{0}^{\pi}y(x,s)ds$.

Suppose that we will use Euler Method with initial conditions $y(0,s)=\cos{s}$ where $s\in[0,\pi]$ and $\Delta x = 1$:

$y(1,s_{1}) = y(0,s_{1}) + (1-0)\left[e^{0}\int_{0}^{\pi}y(0,s)ds \right]\\
y(1,s_{2}) = y(0,s_{2}) + (1-0)\left[e^{0}\int_{0}^{\pi}y(0,s)ds \right]\\
\vdots \\
y'(1,s_{n}) = y(0,s_{n}) + (1-0)\left[e^{0}\int_{0}^{\pi}y(0,s)ds \right]$

Comment: This is not clear what you mean with the integration inside $f$. Could you give a simple example of what you mean? As you write it, the function $f$ in the $k$th equation gets exactly two inputs formed from the current state, $x$ and $y(x,s_k)$. There is no way that an integration over other values of $y$ occurs in the current notation. There is no interaction between the $y$ values for different $s_k$, the equations are decoupled from each other. You could write $$y'(x,s_k)=f\Bigl(x,y(x,s_k),I[y(x,.)]\Bigr)$$ where $I[y(x,.)]=\sum w_ky(x,s_k)$ or $I[y(x,.)]=\int_0^1 w(s)y(x,s)ds$ or so.

Comment: You are right. I edited my question and add an example. In the example, I need to discrete $s$ for the integral.

Comment: Then you can simply discretize the integral at the points $s_k$ so that you get a system in $\vec y(x)=[y_1(x),..,y_n(x)]$ with $y_k(x)=y(x,s_k)$. Is there anything preventing that?

Comment: The main question is what should be the optimal number of bins, $n$ or number of discrete number? Practically, It should be big, but taking big number of $n$ expands the number of diff eqn which slows the simulation.

Comment: That depends on the targeted error. If you want an error of $10^{-6}$ and use a 4th order integration method like Simpson, then you need 30-40 bins per unit lengt, so 100 to 150 for the interval $[0,\pi]$. For higher accuracy accordingly more.

Comment: Thank you for your help. As I understand your comments, it depends on the dynamics of solution. There is not any generic error tolerance formula that predicts to  number of bin. If the solutions are stiffly oscillated, I need to take big number of bins for accurate integral.